# How to test scalar product variables against each other?

Tags: list-manipulation, matrix, linear-algebra, vector

Curious if there is a way to save time with scalar product multiplication with several variables?

I have a 8x4 matrix and i wanna check if all the columns are orthogonal with each other, so ive taken each column and added them to a variable, lets call them a,b,c,d.

Is there a neat way to test all possible scalar products against each other without having to type way to much, even though now its only 4 variables, im thinking that what if i have 100 variables i wanna test against each other?

[image: Assignment]

Here is the matrix A from the assignment if you're interested. :)

```
A = {{-6, -3, 6, 1}, {-1, 2, 1, -6}, {3, 6, 3, -2}
   , {6, -3, 6, -1}, {2, -1, 2, 3}, {-3, 6, 3, 2}
   , {-2, -1, 2, -3}, {1, 2, 1, 6}
   };
```

Answer (score 1):

You may use "Outer" for this purpose:

```
a = {{-6, -3, 6, 1}, {-1, 2, 1, -6}, {3, 6, 3, -2}, {6, -3, 
    6, -1}, {2, -1, 2, 3}, {-3, 6, 3, 2}, {-2, -1, 2, -3}, {1, 2, 1, 
    6}};

Outer[#1 . #2 &, Transpose@a, Transpose@a, 1] // MatrixForm
```

[image]

Comment: Even simpler would be Transpose[a].a